# using web services in mono android under Visual Studio 10

Tags: c#, android, web-services, mono

I have created a very simple web service, and referenced it ok in my project, it all checks out when I define it ...

```
wstest.Service1 ws;
```

ws = new wstest.Service1();
 string xx = ws.HelloWorld();

but when it runs it gets an error (Unhandled Exception / System.Net.WebExceptions)
here

```
public string HelloWorld() {
        object[] results = this.Invoke("HelloWorld", new object[0]);
        return ((string)(results[0]));
    }
```

it seems to know nothing about Invoke ... I'm stuck, any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: ETA .. ait works fine in an ordinary non android c# web